# Same CMIS query returning different results each time?

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I am using alfresco 4.2.2 and using CMIS to fetch content from alfresco repository with query.

> Select * from cmis:document where cmis:contentStreamLength >0

Alfresco repository is having more than 10000 documents but surprisigly, above query is giving different results each time between 3000 to 6000 but not 10000.

Any help please.

Regards.

Comment: You'll get different answers if you connect with different users who have access to differing sites, could that be it?

Comment: Thanks, but i am logging in as admin each time. I tried with CMIS workbench and could see same inconsistent behavior. Are any settings/configuration off the hook here?

Comment: What indexing are you using - SOLR or in-transaction Lucene?

Comment: I am using Solr and to confirm, i reindexed both nodes in cluster.

Comment: Also i have content in it migrated from sharepoint.

Comment: It sounds to me like you've stuffed up the cluster setup then, and you're getting different answers depending on which half of the cluster you hit. I can only suggest you re-visit your cluster setup, and give Alfresco support a call in the morning if you're not sure what has gone wrong.

Comment: Let me check with alfresco support also but other than this would you suggest anything else to verify?